# Can we use a custom action with inherited_resources in a DRY manner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, dry, custom-action, inherited-resources

We have a custom action (:register) for our Location model.  The supporting code is very similar to a standard :update.  Since inherited_resources provided a "template" for us, we copied the update code from actions.rb, changing 'update_attributes' to 'register' and the flash message reflects the different action.
This doesn't feel very DRY.  We would like to **utilize** :update instead.  Any ideas?

```
class LocationsController < InheritedResources::Base
  def register(options={}, &block)
    #TODO: copied update from actions.rb.  I expect there is a better way.
    # All I changed was the flash message (to reflect the action)
    #  and the method call on the object (update_attributes -> register)
    object = resource

    if object.register
      set_flash_message!(:notice, '{{resource_name}} was successfully registered.')
      options[:location] ||= resource_url rescue nil
      respond_with_dual_blocks(object, options, true, block)
    else
      set_flash_message!(:error)
      respond_with_dual_blocks(object, options, false, block)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Inherited resources provides helper methods for CRUD actions which you can override on your controller. The one you look for is

```
  # Responsible for updating the resource in :update method. This allow you
  # to handle how the resource is gona be updated, let's say in a different
  # way then the usual :update_attributes:
  #
  #   def update_resource(object, attributes)
  #     object.reset_password!(attributes)
  #   end
  #
  def update_resource(object, attributes)
    object.update_attributes(attributes)
  end
```

You override it like this:

```
class LocationController < ApplicationController
  inherit_resources

  protected

  def update_resource(object, attributes)
    object.register(attributes)
  end
```

Comment: Incase anyone is still searching for this: In version 1.3 of Inherited Resources, the second parameter passed to update_resource is now an array. I had to use attributes[0] inside of update_resource in order to get the same behavior as before. Given this change, it is probably best not to override update_resource.